# Python3 wifi module returns object, not list of wifi networks

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, wifi

I just installed the wifi library, and started following the guide [here](https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scanning.html), but when I type

```
>>> from wifi import Cell, Scheme
>>> Cell.all('wlan0')
```

The output I get isn't a list, but an object:

```
<map object at 0x7ff23b40e588>
```

I'm using Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, and this does seem to work with Python 2.7, which is fine, but I'd prefer to use 3.4. How do I get the output to be a list? I presume it's just a case of different Python versions handling output differently.

Edit: I've just started trying to figure it out again, and now when I do

```
from wifi import Cell
```

I get this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Cell
```

I'm really confused.

Edit again:

Never mind, that was me being stupid. I made a program called wifi.py to test it, forgetting about the whole idea of modules in Python.

Comment: Have you played with the returned object to see what it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `all` method of `Cell` returns a `map(...)`. In Python 2.x this will *automatically* return a list, but Python 3.x returns a `map` object (an iterator) which can be converted into a list by calling `list` on it.

So you can see the full list of wifi networks by calling `list` on the returned object:

```
>>> list(Cell.all('wlan0'))
```

.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works now. I'm not particularly familiar with the differences between py2 and 3, other than the most obvious ones.

Comment: Additionally it will also work on Python 2.x since calling list(a_list) returns the original list.

Comment: @Isaac274 Note that if you just want to iterating over all networks you should *not* call `list` but just do `for network in Cell.all('wlan0'):`... that's the whole point of the change in python3: to avoid building unneccesary temporary lists.

Comment: @DamiánCastro It does **not** return the original list, it returns *a shallow copy* of the original list. It matters if you try to modify the result.

Comment: @Isaac274 You can find out the changes here: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling with it on my RasperryPi module.